# AJAX loader animation not showing

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have an AJAX script which should trigger a loading image once executed and then hide it once I get the result from the web-service, however the image is now showing.

My code is as below:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function get_Code_Results() {
            document.getElementById("loader").innerHTML = "<img src=\'loading.gif\' />";
            var url = document.location;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            else if (window.ActiveXObject) req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            req.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
    //      req.open("GET", url, true);
    //      req.send(null);
            req.open("POST",url,true);
            req.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            req.send("isbns="+document.getElementById("Code").value);
            function processRequest() {
        if (req.readyState == 4 && document.getElementById("1").checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("results").value = "myfirsturl.com" + req.responseText;
        }
        else if (req.readyState == 4 && document.getElementById("2").checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("results").value = "myurl.com" + req.responseText;
        }           
    }
}
    </script>
```

and I have a position where I want the loader to be displayed:

```
    <div id="loader"><img src="loading.gif" style="display:none;" /></div>
```

Where do I have the mistake in my code? Some advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  <div id="loader"><img src="loading.gif" style="display:none;" /></div>
```

You need to change the `style="display:none;"`. I suggest you write the following code instead :

```
<div id="loader" style="display:none;"><img src="loading.gif" /></div>
```

Then when needed :

```
$('#loader').show(); // To show the laoding icon
$('#loader').hide(); // To hide it
```

Comment: `$('#loader').show();` when the user clicks and initiates the request and after the request is completed : `$('#loader').hide();`

Comment: I finally got it working after some attempts, thank you Cosmin!

Answer (score 1):

Your functions are nested. I guess you pretend to write somethin like:

```
function get_ISBN_Results() {
            document.getElementById("loader").innerHTML = "<img src=\'loading.gif\' />";
            var url = document.location;
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) req = new XMLHttpRequest();
            else if (window.ActiveXObject) req = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            req.onreadystatechange = processRequest;
    //      req.open("GET", url, true);
    //      req.send(null);
            req.open("POST",url,true);
            req.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            req.send("isbns="+document.getElementById("isbns").value);
}
function processRequest() {
        if (req.readyState == 4 && document.getElementById("book").checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("results").value = "myfirsturl.com" + req.responseText;
        }
        else if (req.readyState == 4 && document.getElementById("magazine").checked == true) {
            document.getElementById("results").value = "myurl.com" + req.responseText;
        }           
 }
```